# Tornado curl_httpclient 'reset' connection

Tags: python, tornado

I have a tornado application that makes requests to an http server using curl_httpclient. Every once in a while, all calls to the server returns incorrect results. In other words, the http responses are still fine, but the contents returned by the server becomes incorrect.

I find I can get around this problem by terminating and restarting my process, which seems to mean that if I make a new TCP connection to the server and send new requests, things will be fine.

Now my problem is how to make HTTP requests over a new TCP connection. I tried to replace the http client with a new one like below, but it seems that a new TCP connection is not made and the old connection reused.

```
http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
```

How can I close my existing TCP connection and make a new connection to the server and continue the business?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `force_instance=True` keyword argument to the AsyncHTTPClient constructor to ensure that you get a new object instead of reusing an old one, but it's probably worth figuring out why you're getting "incorrect" results in the first place.

How are the results "incorrect"?  Is it not a well-formed HTTP response?  Is it a response for an earlier (or subsequent pipelined) request on the same connection, or something unrelated?

Make sure you're using an up-to-date version of libcurl - very old versions had a history of problems with the asynchronous interfaces, although I haven't seen any problems in a couple of years.  Note that if you're on a slow-moving distribution like centos this may mean installing libcurl from source instead of getting it from your distribution.  If you don't have a specific need for curl_httpclient you can also use tornado's simple_httpclient instead.

Comment: The response is a well-formed HTTP response and the application level format is also correct. However it has the wrong contents. I think the problem is with the web server application. It probably goes into a race condition from time to time and does not 'see' new updates. I am using the force_instance=True parameter and it now creates a new instance, but it appears to be still using the same TCP connection. Is there any way to make sure the new instance creates a new TCP connection?

Comment: Hmm, a client created with force_instance shouldn't share anything with the previous one.  Are you sure it's related to the reused TCP connection?  And as I said before; only curl_httpclient reuses TCP connections currently; if you use simple_httpclient it will always create a new connection (at least in Tornado 3.2; connection reuse should come in a future version)